# SSO: is it OK to cache the SSO token for some time and thus not contact the auth server on every request?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

For single sign on (SSO) I have a single auth server (with user table) and multiple resource server (various web applications).

So far I have implemented JWT using Oauth 2.0 and got the access token from the auth server.

I understand from the OAuth 2.0 spec that the resource server now have to communicate with the Auth server to validate the token. Which is simple and can be done by just sending `GET` request to auth server at the endpoint `users/me` to get the user object along with other user scope.

Now coming to my point is the *frequency* of the Auth server call from the resource server. Calling auth server for each incoming request to resource server is not efficient and will create slowness because of the extra round trip.

**How often should resource server communicate with the auth server? If not on each request then how do I persist the auth information?**

I was thinking of using session on resource server but I am not sure if that is correct way to go.

Comment: By the way, OAuth is an authorization, not an authentication protocol (though you can put together pseudo-authentication using it): https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your access token contains expiry time, then you can restrict consecutive requests to your resource server for that much time. You can cache access token once obtain and other requests first lookup in cache, also you can periodically check whether access token is still valid or not.